# css: how to make iframe like div?

Tags: css, iframe

css: how to make iframe like div? i.e.,

```
1) width 100%
2) Height: wrap content
3) without scroll
```

HTML

```
<body>

<div>
    <iframe src="foo.html"/>
<div>

<div>
    <iframe src="bar.html"/>
</div>

</body>
```

The iframe has a height, so it always have a scroll bar for large content. Can this be achieved by CSS only?

Answer (score 0):

Code
In foo.html, the following javascript code is required (this can be loaded from a .js file on any domain, incidentally..):

```
<script>
  // Resize iframe to full height
  function resizeIframe(height)
  {
    // "+60" is a general rule of thumb to allow for differences in
    // IE & and FF height reporting, can be adjusted as required..
    document.getElementById('frame_name_here').height = parseInt(height)+60;
  }
</script>
<iframe id='frame_name_here' src='http://www.bar.html'></iframe>
```

In [www.bar.html](http://www.bar.html):

```
<body onload="iframeResizePipe()">
<iframe id="helpframe" src='' height='0' width='0' frameborder='0'></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function iframeResizePipe()
  {
     // What's the page height?
     var height = document.body.scrollHeight;

     // Going to 'pipe' the data to the parent through the helpframe..
     var pipe = document.getElementById('helpframe');

     // Cachebuster a precaution here to stop browser caching interfering
     pipe.src = 'foo.html?height='+height+'&cacheb='+Math.random();

  }
</script>
```

Contents of foo.html:

```
<html> 
<!-- 
This page is on the same domain as the parent, so can
communicate with it to order the iframe window resizing
to fit the content 
--> 
  <body onload="parentIframeResize()"> 
    <script> 
      // Tell the parent iframe what height the iframe needs to be
      function parentIframeResize()
      {
         var height = getParam('height');
         // This works as our parent's parent is on our domain..
         parent.parent.resizeIframe(height);
      }

      // Helper function, parse param from request string
      function getParam( name )
      {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
        var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
        var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
        var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
        if( results == null )
          return "";
        else
          return results[1];
      }
    </script> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As for the width and the border, `style="border:none;width:100%"` can be set on the iframe to make it full width, and remove the border.

As for the height, it depends where the framed page is located.

If the framed page is on the **same domain**, then this can be done with JavaScript:

```
<button onclick="resizeIframe();">Resize iframe</button>
<iframe src="{path on the same domain}" id="iframe" style="border:none;width:100%"></iframe>
<script>
    function resizeIframe() {
        var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe'),
        height = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
        iframe.style.height = height + 'px';
    }
</script>
```

As long as the framed page is on the same domain, this code snippet should work out of the box.

If the framed page is on a **different domain** (mysite.com vs. youtube.com), there is **no way** to access the iframe from the outside, as a security measure.

If this security measure didn't exist, a malicious webpage could do bad things, like stealing your credentials on a website.